# How to send email with hidden BCC and HTML content

Tags: html, hyperlink, hidden, smtplib, bcc

That's my first post here :)
This is the first python I ever made.
I'm trying to write a script that will send an e-mail when run.
About this e-mail there are 3 important things for me:

1) There's no "To" - only "CC" and "BCC".

2) BCC - there are a lot of addresses under BCC, all of them must get the e-mail but other e-mail addresses must be hidden.

3) I want to add a hyperlink for a word.

I have tried to use the MIMEMultipart, but I could not find a way to make the BCC work as I want (I went all over google and stackoverflow and couldn't get it to work).
I was able to achieve the sending an e-mail with hidden BCC to work as I want but it's without using MIMEMultipart - using only smtplib, however I can't seem to understand how to integrate the html part.

```
def send_email():
password = '*********'
bcc = ['danielofir8@gmail.com','danielofirpython@gmail.com']
from_addr = 'danielofirsales@gmail.com'
to_addr = ''
cc_addr = 'danielofirsales@gmail.com'
mail_subject = "Testing E-mail"
content = "Maintenance on the New York data center will be performed on Sunday, July 1st, 2018 at 06:30 UTC.\nWe expect to complete the maintenance by Sunday, July 1st, 2018 at 08:30 "

body = f"From: {from_addr}\r\n" + f"To: {to_addr}\r\n" + f"Cc: {cc_addr}\r\n" + f"Subject: {mail_subject}\r\n" + "\r\n"  + content
to_addr = [to_addr] + [cc_addr] + bcc

try:
    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
    server.ehlo()
    server.starttls()
    server.login('danielofirsales@gmail.com',password)
    server.sendmail(from_addr, to_addr ,body)
    server.quit()
    print("Success")
except:
    print("Failed")
send_email()
```

I found a code someone here wrote on how to use the MIMEMultipart to send HTML in the e-mail and was able to send the e-mail with the hyperlink, however everytime a try to add BCC (couple different ways I found online), I get an error.

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
password = '*******'
from_adr='danielofirsales@gmail.com'
to_adr='danielofirpython@gmail.com'

msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
msg['Subject'] = "Emailing a link"
msg['From'] = 'danielofirsales@gmail.com'
msg['To'] = 'danielofirpython@gmail.com'

html = """
<html>
<head></head>
  <body>
    <p>Maintenance on the New York data center will be performed on Sunday, July 1st, 2018 at 06:30 UTC.\nAs published on our
    <a href="http://www.google.com">Status Page</a> - We expect to complete the maintenance by Sunday, July 1st, 2018 at 08:30</p>
  </body>
</html>
"""

part1=MIMEText(html, 'html')
part2=MIMEText("Maintenance on the New York data center will be performed on Sunday, July 1st, 2018 at 06:30 UTC.\nAs published on our http://www.google.com - We expect to complete the maintenance by Sunday, July 1st, 2018 at 08:30", 'text')

msg.attach(part1)
msg.attach(part2)


server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
server.ehlo()
server.starttls()
server.login('danielofirsales@gmail.com',password)
server.sendmail(msg['From'], msg['To'] ,msg.as_string())
server.quit()
print("Success")
```

Is there a way to use the hidden BCC option of smtplib and the html option of MIMEMultipart?

Also important, currently the script should send e-mail through Gmail, but when actually applied it will send the e-mail from the company's e-mail server.

Thanks ahead for the help :)

Daniel.

Comment: Much apologies, I just posted my solution.

Comment: Thanks! I removed my comment :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I was able to find some way to acheive what I wanted. Basically the "hard" part was to use the MIMETEXT to also add the hearder in the smtplib format. (header)
Hope this helps someone in the future :)

```
def send_mail():
pop_input= input("Please write the PoP's name: ")
password = '*******'



from_adr='danielofirsales@gmail.com'
cc_adr='danielofirsales@gmail.com'
to_adr = ''
mail_subject = ''

msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
msg['Subject'] = f"Planned Maintenance on the {pop_input} PoP"
msg['From'] = 'danielofirsales@gmail.com'
msg['Cc'] = 'danielofirsales@gmail.com'

content = f"As published on our https://www.google.com, a maintenance on {pop_input}."
html = """
<html>
<head></head>
  <body>
    <p>As published on our
    <a href="https://www.google.com">Status Page</a>, a maintenance on {POP}</p>
  </body>
</html>
"""
new_html = html.format(POP=pop_input,START_TIME=start_message,END_TIME=end_message)
header = MIMEText(f"From: {from_adr}\r\n" + f"Cc: {cc_adr}\r\n" + f"Subject: {mail_subject}\r\n" + "\r\n",'plain') 


bcc = ['danielofir8@gmail.com','danielofirpython@gmail.com']
to_adr = [to_adr] + [cc_adr] + bcc

part1=MIMEText(new_html, 'html')
part2=MIMEText(content, 'text')

msg.attach(header)
msg.attach(part1)
msg.attach(part2)

try:
    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
    server.ehlo()
    server.starttls()
    server.login('danielofirsales@gmail.com',password)
    server.sendmail(from_adr, to_adr ,msg.as_string())
    server.quit()
    print("Success")
except:
    print("Failed")
```